# Return an error if any of the value in the list does not exist in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2014

I have a table like the below.

[image: EmployeeTable]

I want to pass a list of values in the select query using the IN clause. For e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName IN ('Tim','Bob','Jim')
```

Is there a way to modify the query to return an error if any of the records in the list of values does not exist in the table.

For e.g.

Case 1 : 
If the input to the query is **('Tim','Bob','Jim')**, it should return an error since Jim is not existing in the table.

Case 2 : 
If the input to the query is **('Tim','Bob')** it should not return an error since all the entries in the list are existing in the DB table.

Case 3 : 
If the input to the query is **('Tim','Bob','Rick','Sam','Gary')** it should not return an error.

In a nutshell, I want to return an error if any of the values from the input List does not exist in the table.

I would want to know whether this is feasible and if so is it a good practice. 
We are using SQL SERVER 2014.

Comment: What say "return a value if..." What value should be returned?

Comment: Apologies for the editing mistake. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Why would you want your SQL to error if something passes an employee that isn't in your table? This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can left join `employee` to the list and check for a `NULL` i.e. no matching row was found in `employee`. Use `EXISTS` on that result in the outer query.

```
SELECT <your value>
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM (VALUES ('Tim'),
                                         ('Bob'),
                                         ('Jim')) v (name)
                                 LEFT JOIN employee e
                                           ON e.employeename = v.name
                            WHERE e.employeename IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot. I was wondering whether we can do this without JOIN operation.

Comment: @MohitBansal: What's the problem when using a `JOIN`?